# Disable horizontal scroll in touchscreen

Tags: javascript, jquery, horizontal-scrolling, touchscreen

First a little supporting information:
Currently I am making touchscreen navigation, similar to the iOS facebook app. It requires one div to be slided away from the screen(almost completely). For this I am using jqueryUI draggable. My problem arises when the div has been slided away, but the user continues to slide horizontally(the div can be moved into strange places). That is why I decided to write a script to completely disable all kinds of horizontal scrolling(no CSS overflox-x:hidden doesn't help).

My idea is to compare the speeds of the finger in the X and Y axis. You can see my code below.
This works fine when it comes down to purely horizontal scroll, but breaks when doing some diagonal movement.
Anybody have ideas on how I could block out this diagonal scrolling without completely disabling scroll everywhere.

```
var t1,sX,sY;//vars for the initial touch start time and position

$(window).bind('touchstart',function(e){
    dateX = new Date();//time at start
    t1 = dateX.getTime();

    sX = event.changedTouches[0].clientX;//starting x coordinates
    sY = event.changedTouches[0].clientY;//starting y coordinates
});

$(window).bind('touchmove',function(e){
    dateX = new Date();//get current x time
    var t2 = dateX.getTime();

    var T = t2 - t1;//substract initial from it

    var s1X = Math.abs( event.changedTouches[0].clientX - sX);//get current x coordinates and substract initial from them
    var s1Y = Math.abs( event.changedTouches[0].clientY - sY);//get current y coordinates and substract initial from them

//speed of finger in px/ms
     var X=Math.abs(s1X/T);
     var Y=Math.abs(s1Y/T);

//absolute value of the speeds and if moving horizontally, dont scroll

if(X>Y){
    e.preventDefault();
}
});
```